# Mean Value Theorem demonstration

Tags: rolles-theorem

> $\large f(x)=\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{x^2}) -\ln(x^2+1)$
>
> $\large if  1\leq x < y$  $\large \text { and } 1-\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\geq 0$

Demonstrate that

> $ \large |f(x)-f(y)|\leq 2|x-y|$

I managed to get a quadratic équation in term of $c$  through the expression $f'(c)=\frac{f(y)-f(1)}{y-1}$. then I determined  $f'(x)$ and made the substitution with c then compared both $f'(c)$ But I did not manage to get further.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the result is true, since $f'(1) \approx -2.74$ which is greater than $2$ in absolute value. So for instance, if we take $x=1$ and $y=1.1$, we have
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=0.298\\
f(y)&=0.033\\
|f(x)-f(y)|&=0.265\\
|x-y|&= 0.1
\end{align*}
so $|f(x)-f(y)|>2|x-y|$.